# sybase database process visualization

Tags: database-design, process, sybase, data-visualization, business-process-management

I am looking for a tool that can take a view or stored procedure and graphically represent the workflow in an illustration such as visio (or really any flow chart)

Essentially what i am looking to do is take a sybase view and stored procedure and run a report (via tool) that essentially shows all of the inputs and outputs (all views, inserts/updates to tables, etc.)

I am working on a project to document all input and extract feeds of a trading system and most of the end of day batch work happens in the database via stored procs referencing tables/views.   would really love a tool to do most of the heavy lifting putting the pieces together.

---work smart not hard

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SAP Sybase PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner).  It should have the features you are looking for.